# Is there a standard way to make sure a python script will be interpreted by python2 and not python3?

Tags: python, unix, scripting, python-3.x, shebang

Is there a standard way to make sure a python script will be interpreted by python2 and not python3? On my distro, I can use #!/usr/bin/env python2 as the shebang, but it seems not all distros ship "python2". I could explicitly call a specific version (eg. 2.6) of python, but that would rule out people who don't have that version.

It seems to me that this is going to be increasingly a problem when distros will start putting python3 as the default python interpreter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a messy issue during what will be a very long transition time period.  Unfortunately, there is no fool-proof, cross-platform way to guarantee which Python version is being invoked, other than to have the Python script itself check once started.  Many, if not most, distributions that ship Python 3 are ensuring the generic `python` command is aliased by default to the most recent Python 2 version while `python3` is aliased to the most recent Python 3.  Those distributions that don't should be encouraged to do so. But there is no guarantee that a user won't override that.  I think the best practice available for the foreseeable future is to for packagers, distributors, and users to assume `python` refers to Python 2 and, where necessary, build a run-time check into the script.

Comment: And, if necessary, as kwatford points out in his comment, include a check at install time in the package's `setup.py` script or equivalent since `setuptools`, `Distribute`, `pip` et al. generally alter scripts' shebang lines to point to the installing Python instance.

Comment: IMHO there always should be available symlink `python2` in order to make in future, [clearly distinguishable shebangs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26573/python-python2-or-python-python3-how-to-package-distribute-python-py2k)

Comment: @Grzegorz: Python PEP 394 is open on that subject and will likely get implemented in a future update to Python 2: http://bugs.python.org/issue12627

Answer (score 12):

http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version_info

using the sys module you can determine the version of python that is running and raise an exception or exit or whatever you like.

UPDATE:

You could use this to call the appropriate interpreter.  For example, set up a small script that does the checking for you, and use it in the shbang.  It would check the python version running, and if not what you want, looks for one you want.  Then it would run the script in that version of python (or fail if nothing good was found).

Answer (score 8):

Using `sys.version_info` you can do a simple value test against it. For example if you only want to support version 2.6 or lower:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info > (2,6):
    sys.exit("Sorry, only we only support up to Python 2.6!")
```

Comment: That's not what I want, I want the good interpreter to be chosen automatically, not to print an error message if the wrong one is chosen :-/

Comment: The definitive answer to your question is: "No, there is no standard way to make sure a python script will be interpreted by python2 and not python3." 

What you asked for was to make sure that Python2 was chosen over 3. You did not specify that you wanted the correct interpreter to be chosen automatically.

The only way you might be able to do this for sure would be to implement a check prior to the program being called (such as with a shell script) that then runs your Python code against the desired Python interpreter.

Comment: Expecting "the good interpreter to be chosen automatically" is absurd. A file can't force which program runs it.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same situation, but the company I work for has an app that can run Python scripts (among its many features). After numerous support issues involving Python installations on various platforms, we decided to just install our own Python interpreter with the app. That way we know exactly where it is installed and what version it is. This approach may be too heavyweight for your needs (the Python package is only about 10% of our app's bits) but it definitely works.

Comment: This is actually a great approach that cuts out all the jiggering required for such a rigid requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you're distributing it, I guess.

If you're using a normal `setup.py` file to manage your distribution, have it bomb out if the user is trying to install it in Python 3.

Once it's installed, the shebang of the console script created by (say) setuptools will likely be linked to the specific interpreter used to install it.

If you're doing something weird for your installation, you can in whatever installation script you're using look for python interpreters and store a choice. You might first check whether whatever is called "python" is a 2.x. If not, check for "python2.7", "python2.6", etc to see what's available.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand different distros will be in different locations in your drive. Here are some suggestions that come to mind -

1. You could use UNIX alias to create shortcuts pointing to the different distros. Eg: alias py2="/usr/bin/python2.X". So when you run your script you could use py2 xx.py
2. Or other way could be to modify your PYTHON_PATH environment variable.
3. Or if I am not wrong there is a provision in sys module to get the current python version number. You could get that & deal appropriately.

This should do it...

Comment: I'm distributing a python app, my problem is to make sure **all users** use python2.x to run my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autotools to pick a Python 2 interpreter.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173018/1207160) is how to do that.  Guaranteeing a correct shebang may be tricky to do elegantly; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188285/1207160) is one way to do that.  It may be easier to simply have a light Bash wrapper script, `wrapper.sh.in` that looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON2="@PYTHON@" #That first link enables this autotool variable
"$PYTHON2" "$@"  #Call the desired Python 2 script with its arguments
```

Call `wrapper.sh` (after a `./configure`) like:

```
./wrapper.sh my_python2_script.py --an_option an_argument
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will do what you want, namely test for a non-specific version of Python less than 3.x (as long as it doesn't contain a `from __future__ import print_function` statement).

```
try:
    py3 = eval('print')
except SyntaxError:
    py3 = False

if py3: exit('requires Python 2')
...
```

It works by testing to see if `print` is a built-in function as opposed to a statement, as it is in Python3. When it's not a function, the `eval()` function will raise an exception, meaning the code is running on a pre-Python 3.0 interpreter with the caveat mentioned above.