# Any reason not to use /usr/bin/env python2/python3 explicitly?

Tags: python, environment-variables, versioning

I often see this at the top of `.py` files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

With the unknown state of the OS defaults, I wonder why it's not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

If most OSs provide this versioned symlink, wouldn't that be better?

I found [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) while looking around, which states that for the time being, developers should assume `python -> python2 -> python2.x`. It *also* states that one can assume that the versioned equivalents, `python3` and `python2`, exist. So what's the harm in *not* leaving it to chance and providing that extra character?

If one doesn't have `python2` installed because the OS ships by default with `python -> python3` (like Arch linux), I'd much prefer this issue when running a script or program:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python2’: No such file or directory
```

Alternatively, this error is much worse, particularly for a new user (`python` exists, it's just the wrong version):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  print 'Hello world'
                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

That said, I find the latter far more common. At least now I know some typical compatibility errors well enough to think to myself "Oh, right. It's the `python` symlink."

Two questions ask *how* to specify/verify the desired version:

- [This 2010 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586776/is-there-a-standard-way-to-make-sure-a-python-script-will-be-interpreted-by-pyth) suggests treating `python` as meaning `python2` and `python3` as required to explicitly call out `python3`.
- [This 2013 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625768/is-there-a-standard-way-to-make-sure-a-python-script-will-be-interpreted-by-pyth): maybe implies that `python3` shouldn't be used because not all distros ship with it?

Is there an obvious reason I (or `python` programmers) *shouldn't* use a versioned `env` call if most OSs provide it? To use just `python` is seeming to cater to a minority who don't have the versioned command while causing confusion to the vast majority who do.

Maybe the answer *is* to use versioned commands (I'm getting that from PEP 394) but enough time hasn't elapsed to see them appear. To date I've never seen a versioned `env` call... then again, if it works I never look. If it breaks, it's always a version-less `python` line so my mental counts are probably skewed!

---

Some github stats on searches; I was curious on usage:

- `#!/usr/bin/env python2`: ~210k python file code hits
- `#!/usr/bin/env python3`: ~460k
- `#!/usr/bin/env python`: ~6 million

This could mean that most code is old enough that if the recommendations of the questions above was the prevailing wisdom, folks just haven't updated their files?

---

I looked at these popular OSs and found them all to use versioned commands:

- ubuntu: [python-minimal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/python-minimal/filelist) and [python3-minimal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/python3-minimal/filelist)
- arch: [python](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/python/files/) and [python2](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/python2/)
- fedora: [python2](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/python2/) and [python3](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/python3/)
- debian: same names/state as ubuntu
- [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac) sources [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x) that OS X [uses](http://joebergantine.com/articles/installing-python-2-and-python-3-alongside-each-ot/) versioned commands
- windows: I think [there's evidence](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions) that windows has versioned commands available

Comment: You could use just `#!/usr/bin/env python` if your code is Python2/3 compatible. But I think that's a very minimal amount of code that works that way. Most of it is heritage from before Python 3, including tutorials etc that still suggest to use `/usr/bin/env python`, without warning about the consequences.

Comment: fwiw, the default installation of python on windows **doesn't** adhere to pep394 -- it just provides `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`

Comment: @Evert of course after I wrote this, that dawned on me :) I think I just saw an example of that with some `import __future__` stuff, and that now makes sense. Very valid that if you've written compatible code you don't need to care.

Comment: This question is the number one reason I don't recommend anyone to learn python or use it for anything.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I hear you, but I feel like there's plenty of "learn once, never need to learn again"  quirks for any language. This legit only affects deployment, so at the very least "use it for anything" is a huge overreaction (does not impact single computer use cases). Imagine someone struggling with `gdb` and debug compiler flags for the first time and then advocating no one should ever learn C.

Comment: The problem is insidious in that it ends up on user's machines, and has no satisfactory solution. Don't get me wrong, I love python3; but we need to fix the problem that people and their machines think all python scripts are compatible with all interpreter versions.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I can dig that answer. If anything hopefully [this](https://pythonclock.org/) can make for a saner future :)

Comment: For instance, consider [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767292/importerror-no-module-named-lsb-release) question; the writers of the lsb_release package have assumed that python 3.6 would be backwards compatible, which is a reasonable assumption if you know what semantic versioning is. But if you try to import the 'lsb_release' package under python3.6, you will find it missing. (it is present in python3.5)

Comment: I, for one, am adding `#!/bin/env python3.9` to all my python3.9 scripts, and am not assuming that it will work with python3.10.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the script, you may induce various dependencies on a particular version of Python. Use a dict comprehension? You need at least Python 2.7. Using the `async` keyword? You need at least Python 3.5.

When you use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, you aren't saying *anything* about which version of Python is required to execute your script; you are just saying "Use whatever version of Python is found in your path first." Fundamentally, the developer is the wrong person to specify the shebang.

Instead, the *user* should be setting the shebang to the path of the correct version of Python on *their* system.

The `distutils` package strikes a good compromise here. You, the developer, just put `#!python` in your script. When you install the script via `python setup.py install`, the installer replaces `#!python` with whatever path is correct on the target machine.

Comment: I sort of get this... but "my system" is also a agglomeration of all the software installed on it. So, say I want to code in `python3`, my OS (arch) assumes `python == python3`, and I install software from someone ([like this](https://github.com/gepd/Deviot/issues/64)) who wrote it for v2.7. Which is "the correct" version for my system?

Comment: Also, if the developer has an instance of `print 'blah'` in his/her code, then they *have* specified the shebang (implicitly). Part of my question is indirectly asking why software currently written/updated isn't acknowledging this (which led me to wonder if maybe there's a deeper reason than "because history was written in `python2` and that's what we've always done").

Comment: Not the user; the *installer* should set the hash-bang (whether the installer be a package manager, an administrator or an end-user doesn't matter).

Comment: @Evert Thanks, that's a good clarification. I was using "user" as a (intentionally) vague stand-in for whoever runs the package manager.