# How do I run code from a different directory with a bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have been putting my code on github, but I've run into an implementation snag. I run the same code on many computers (including a computer that I do not have root access on).

One piece of code (a bash script) calls some python code like:

```
python somecode.py
```

The shell will run the correct version of python, but it won't find somecode.py.

What I've tried:

Fail #1: I tried to add both the directory which contains somecode.py and the full path to the file to the PATH; to no avail. [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Fail #2: I can make it work for one computer ONLY if I add the full path to the correct version of python in the top line:

```
#!/usr/local/cool/python/version/location
```

However this breaks it running on any other computer.

Fail #3: I can also make it work if I make the bash script say:

```
python /full/path/to/github/place/somecode.py
```

but again, this only works for ONE computer because the paths are different for different computers.

**What I really want to do**: I want to be able to use the same code (both bash script and somecode.py) on multiple computers.

Any suggestions about how to do this properly is welcome. Thanks!

### Solution

Added:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

To the top of my somecode.py code;

```
mv somecode.py somecode
chmod +x somecode
```

Make sure PATH has /full/path/to/directory/with/somecode.

Bash script now says only:

```
somecode
```

and it works.

Comment: Where is your bash script located?

Comment: Ako: my bash script is located in the same directory as the python script. I run the bash script in a directory far away from that directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For problem #2 try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

though it may find different versions of Python on different machines, but as long as that's not a problem this should fix that particular problem

See this SO question [Python deployment and /usr/bin/env portability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705/python-deployment-and-usr-bin-env-portability) too. And this post by [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/1209279) re use of this.

Comment: @JBWhitmore How does that fix your `No Such File or Directory` problem?

Comment: @Tim, figured it was long enough to append how I fixed it to the question. The "no such file" error was just when I tried that particular workaround to the problem. It now works just fine.

Comment: @JBWhitmore Ah, I misunderstood.  The "no such file" error was a result of your shabang path, not of not finding the `somecode.py`.  Alright then, congrats and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

If you say `python somefile.py` then it will take the location of `somefile.py` as the current directory, not from `$PATH`.  It will take the location of `python` from `$PATH`.

If you say `somefile.py` then it will take the location of `somefile.py` from `$PATH`, and the location of `python` from the `#!` line of your python script, which can use the PATH if you follow @Levon's suggestion.